# how to make imported data from array update in AS3.0/Flex?

Tags: xml, arrays, actionscript-3

I think I must be missing a step here; I have different data being pulled from an array created from xml depending on a variable (_currentTrackNum).. and the data changes if I set a different initial value for it; but if I change the variable once the program is initialized, none of the data changes even though I rerun the call with the changed variable.

```
<s:HTTPService id="playlistxml" url="playlist.xml" result="init(event)" fault="noData(event)" />

<fx:Script> 
  <![CDATA[ 
private var _currentTrackNum:int; 
public var playlistdata:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
public var locationarray:Array = new Array();

private function init(event:ResultEvent):void 
{ 
    playlistdata = event.result.playlist.track;
    for (var i:Number=0;i<playlistdata.length;i++){
        locationarray.push(playlistdata[i].location);
        }

    _currentTrackNum = 0;     

    _soundObj = new Sound(); 
    _soundObj.load(new URLRequest(locationarray[_currentTrackNum])); 
    _soundChannel = new SoundChannel(); 

private function playSound():void     
    { 
    _soundChannel = _soundObj.play(); 
    _isPlayingSound = true;         
    } 

private function nextTrack():void     
    { 
    if(_currentTrackNum != locationarray.length()){ 

    _currentTrackNum ++; 
    _soundObj.load(new URLRequest(locationarray[_currentTrackNum])); 
    } 
    }
```

I have tried with strings as well as sound objects so I know that the problem lies not with the handling of the soundchannel.

for reference, here is my xml structure:

```
<playlist> 

  <title>myplaylist</title> 

  <track> 
    <artist>The National</artist> 
    <title>Secret Meeting</title>     
    <location>http://localhost:8888/aim/Discography/uploads/4233019.mp3</location> 
    <album>Alligator</album> 
    <image>http://localhost:8888/aim/Discography/uploads/pics/alligator.jpg</image> 
  </track> 
</playlist>
```

Comment: what is your xml structure if `event.result.playlist.track` stores a list of paths for different tracks?

Comment: also, length() is not a method of array, it's a property.  where you have if(_currentTrackNum != locationarray.length()), that's incorrect.  it's array.length ...property... and xmllist.length() ...method...

Comment: BIg Momo.. you mean i shouldn't have the ()?

Comment: www0z0k... event.result is because it's an mxml result event grabbing the data from the xml..  i put the xml structure in there in case it helps.  what's really weird though is everything's coming out of the xml, and things change if I alter the _currentTrackNum variable at init, but nothing changes when it changes while the prog is running

Comment: excellent.. makes sense! though the overall problem is still.. problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using FlashBuilder , set a breakpoint just after playlistdata as been populated with the XML results, then look at the content of playlistdata. To do this , simply click the variables tab in the debug perspective .

A first guess would be that the results are not properly parsed and for some reason your Array may only contain one element or has been filled with the same element.

If playlistdata is properly populated , set another breakpoint later on in the process and you should find where it all breaks...

Comment: I definitely appreciate the advice! Unfortunately I am currently unable to get FB to run in debug :/. It says to make sure I am running the debug version of flashplayer.. which i've installed a few times without luck.

Comment: I got the debugger working. just had to open flash debug player separately, change it so debug doesn't actually launch anything. hit debug, and then load the swf it generates before it times out...